# Android. Range DatePicker Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, datepicker, android-material

Не у кого нету библиотеки похожий на данный Range DatePicker

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пока что, только такую использую, но она не практична.

[image: https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker]

Дополнение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: трудно будет показать промежуток, если даты находятся в разных месяцах, например.

Comment: @metalurgus, эта либа такое умеет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да я уже по ченжлогу посмотрел. Интересно, как они отображают это...

Comment: @metalurgus, у них довольно гибкая система применения селекторов, фона и цвета текста для каждой ячейки. Например, я делал так, что крайние даты кругами отмечены, а всё, что меж ними - линией широкой.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня вопрос появился, а как можно выбрать дату, например только год (2018) и чтоб календарь про крутился на этот год. А то у меня, он просто стоит на дефолте (2016) и после выбора 2018, он ставит дату на 2018, но календарь стоит на 2016 и приходится вручную прокручивать на 2018 год. Вы не знаете как исправить такую проблему. Был бы очень благодарен. А библиотека то, что надо)

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, несколько вариантов. Если даты до 18 года не нужны, то можно установить границы доступных дат начиная с 18 года. Либо вы как-то не так дату задаёте не так и не вызывается слушатель, переключающий на нужный месяц/год. Либо это баг либы. В таком случае надо саму либу поправить. Последнее можно проверить поставив дату на ноябрь, например, и посмотрев будет ли автоматом перекинуто

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в либе бага. Уже проверил. Но не знаю где её исправить. А еще такой вопрос, как можно сделать как вы говорили начальная дата и конечная - кружочки, а все что между ними полоса например. И как можно задавать радиус для кружочков, чтоб их сделать более менее меньше.

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, я делал, на самом деле аццким костылём т.к. дизайнерам не нравилось первое решение. А оно заключалось в подстановке чрез декораторы круга и полосы в виде фона, сделанного в xml-drawable. Отступы ждя круга полосы делал через inset для LayerDrawable программно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а вот по default после клика на день, стоит белый, как можно изменить данный цвет?

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, если вы про цвет текста, то надо в декораторе  addForegroundSpan добавить. Или в селекторе для текста цвет выделенного текста определить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а как это делается? И можете пожалуйста рассказать, как правильно ставить отдельную иконку для начала и для конца, а то у меня пока что получается просто изменять иконку в декораторе. Выше дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть декораторов библиотеки [Material Calendar View](http://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) такова:

1. Вы создаёте декоратор, в котором определяете какие даты должна быть декорированы и как
2. Чтобы декорировать по разному конец, начало и середину интервала дат вам нужны 2 декоратора.
3. В первый передайте CalendarDay начала и конца промежутка. В методе декоратора shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) возвращайте результат сравнивания пришедшего дня и дней, переданных в декоратор при его создании.

Так вы сможете назначать разный фон/селектор/цвет текста для разных выбранных дней.

Вот примеры декораторов для границ промежутка дат и для их середины.

```
private class StartDayViewDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    private static final int NUM_OF_DAY_CELLS_FROM_LEFT_TO_RIGHT = 7;
    private CalendarDay startDay;
    private boolean start;

    private StartDayViewDecorator(CalendarDay calendarDays, boolean start) {
        startDay = calendarDays;
        this.start = start;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return day.equals(startDay);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {

        int topBottomPadding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.default_margin_small);

        int halfCellWidth = Utils.getScreenWidth() / NUM_OF_DAY_CELLS_FROM_LEFT_TO_RIGHT / 2 + topBottomPadding;

        if (start) {
            LayerDrawable bg = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.bg_circle_primary_with_padding_and_rect_start);

            bg.setLayerInset(0, halfCellWidth, topBottomPadding, 0, topBottomPadding);
            bg.setLayerInset(1, 0, topBottomPadding, 0, topBottomPadding);

            view.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
        } else {
            LayerDrawable bg = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.bg_circle_primary_with_padding_and_rect_end);

            bg.setLayerInset(0, 0, topBottomPadding, 0, topBottomPadding);
            bg.setLayerInset(1, 0, topBottomPadding, halfCellWidth - topBottomPadding, topBottomPadding);
            bg.setLayerInset(2, 0, topBottomPadding, 0, topBottomPadding);

            view.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
        }

        view.setSelectionDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.calendar_day_selector_out_range_transparent));

        view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE));
    }
}

private class InnerDayViewDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    private Set<CalendarDay> mCalendarDays;

    private InnerDayViewDecorator(Set<CalendarDay> calendarDays) {
        mCalendarDays = calendarDays;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return mCalendarDays.contains(day);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.setSelectionDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.calendar_day_selector_out_range_transparent));
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.calendar_day_selector_in_range));

        view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE));
    }
}
```